# Why is br tag or hr tag not working properly inside vuejs template?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I have been learning vuejs cli and am creating a sample website, where one can list their articles. But, incidently the br tag that is used to break into multiple lines isnt working. When I tried hr, which adds a horizontal line, on the front end. It ended up in a huge horizontal space. You can find the complete code details below:

I have tried placing the br tags in multiple locations but it didnt work.

I create the project using `vue create frontend`
Inside the frontend folder, I removed HelloWorld.vue and added ListAllArticles.vue, with the following code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="../assets/propic.jpg" alt="Profile Pic">
      <h3>This is title 1</h3>
      <p>This is title description 1</p><br>
      <p>By John Doe</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="../assets/propic.jpg" alt="Profile Pic">
      <h3>This is title 2</h3><br>
      <p>This is title description 2</p><br>
      <p>By John Doe</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="../assets/propic.jpg" alt="Profile Pic">
      <h3>This is title 3</h3><br>
      <p>This is title description 3</p><br>
      <p>By John Doe</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

hr {
background-color: #eee;
border: 0 none;
color: #eee;
height: 2px;
}
</style>
```

.
The corresponding router index.js is

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import ListAllArticles from '@/components/ListAllArticles'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'ListAllArticles',
      component: ListAllArticles
    }
  ]
})
```

The corresponding index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>markit</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

  </body>
</html>
```

The interesting thing is that even the class img-rounded isnt working.

The output with br tag is as shown here: https://ibb.co/q0nP3Mx

While, when I add hr tag, the output is here: https://ibb.co/tcFz0bF

As you can see the br/hr tag isnt working as expected, and am unable to handle this

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with vue, but with the CSS that you use (but which you don't provide to us). Also, there's not a single element with a class of "img-rounded", so how's that supposed to work?

Comment: img-rounded is a part of bootstrap class. So, that should work anyways, right? There is no custom css included here. So, where can custom css be present?